# Mounting multiple BlockDeviceMappings to an EC2 instance using Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ebs

I'm trying to mount multiple EBS volumes to my EC2 instance using cloudformation, but for some reason, only the last EBS volume that I specify gets mounted.

```
EG:
NewEC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    DependsOn: OldSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref pImageId
      InstanceType: !Ref pInstanceType
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        -
          DeviceName: /dev/sda1
          Ebs:
            VolumeSize: 10
          DeviceName: /dev/sdf
          Ebs:
            VolumeSize: 11
            Encrypted: true
          DeviceName: /dev/sdg
          Ebs:
            VolumeSize: 12
            Encrypted: true 
          DeviceName: /dev/sdh
          Ebs:
            VolumeSize: 100
            Encrypted: true
```

For the above code, only the 100Gb /dev/sdh gets created.

I think Cloudformation is overwriting the EBS volumes.

Anyone know why? Please help!

Comment: Please paste into notepad to look at code

Answer (score 5):

You miss a `-` in front of each device name. Like so:

```
  BlockDeviceMappings:
  - DeviceName: "/dev/xvda"
    Ebs:
      VolumeSize: 16
      VolumeType: gp2
  - DeviceName: "/dev/xvdf"
    Ebs:
      VolumeSize: 12
      VolumeType: gp2
```

With only one `-` you were actually defining an array with a single element with conflicting keys, the default behavior for yaml is to use the last key it find in the object.